# How do you update a non-dedicated server?

Tags: ark-survival-evolved

The new update, featuring the Procoptodon, was just released to Xbox One consoles.

I am running a non-dedicated server, but have not seen one, yet. I can not even find the saddle.

How do I update my non-dedicated server?

Comment: By non-dedicated do you mean playing in single player?  Also, you'll need to either kill a bunch of dinosaurs or use the admin console to use the command DestroyWildDinos, which has probably been mentioned plenty online.

Comment: Yes I mean single player. I don't think the update happend at all. Because when I go to the engram list I can't find the saddle.

Comment: Does it tell you if there's an update available in steam?  Also when you are at the main menu, what version does it tell you on the bottom left?

Comment: I'm on a Xbox one. On the home screen it says that a new version has been released January 10th.

Comment: Im not sure the update occurred for anyone, I'm not seeing it on my XB1, and the home screen message say the update occurs **the week of Jan 10**. In any case, it would update your server when the game updates, since a non dedicated console server is specific to your console/game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay Manuel, I forgot you were on XBox One, but I was hoping it would give you a version number.  So as of today, there hasn't been an update to add the `Procoptodon`, but it is listed as an ETA for this week.  It also looks like they post XBox One update notes there, so I would also suggest going to http://survivetheark.com/index.php?/forums/forum/5-changelog-patch-notes/ for any patch notes.

Here's the link directly to the XBox One patch notes that you are looking for.

http://survivetheark.com/index.php?/forums/topic/1468-xbox-patch-notes-v7300-eta-week-of-january-10/

```
Upcoming Version v730.0

All the PC Functionality, Fixes, & Content up through PC version v231.9 
(Fireplace, Procoptodon, Dino Rebalance, etc)
Fixed Cave Loading crash/fall-thru
Improved performance: better framerate, less stalls
Fixed crosshair not appearing
Fixed some cases where you could lose character save data in local mode
Fixed fur armor colorization
Added 100+ more Official Servers
Improved speed of server listing
[MORE NOTES TO COME]
```

Also as a heads up, more information in your question is helpful, so we don't have to go back and forth on comments to get the information we need.  In this case I mainly needed to see if you meant non-dedicated as in single player, and what update you were on (still not sure where that is on XBox One).  `V730.0` is the one that you want, but they are pretty good about getting the patch notes updated as they are patching (meaning check there first).

Edit: also I forgot to mention, just make sure to keep your XBox One game updated, but you may have gotten `V729.9` earlier and that caused the confusion.  They said the week of Jan 10th, not on that day.

Comment: Kinda new the forums. Sorry about the confusion. But thank you for the answer! That clarifies a lot for me. Thanks again

Comment: @Manuel It's not a problem, it takes some getting use to, but think of it like this.  The forums are meant for specific questions that can be answered, while providing as much information as you can that would help others.  There's plenty on the help page about how to make good questions, but I would suggest editing your question to be more specific about your issue and less about updating a non-dedicated server.  Generally you get a downvote because of a bad question/answer, but you can still fix it.